# How to use "sed" to find out only matched variables?

Tags: bash, sed

My string is `MSE: 16.80 (MSE is lower) [15 16.3 18.8 11]`. Using `sed` I want to select only `16.80 (MSE is lower)` i.e, I want to select variables between ":" and "[". How can I do that?

Comment: Just so you know, a likely reason that your question has attracted downvotes is that you haven't shown any attempt to solve this problem yourself. It is useful to show what you've tried and explain the specific problems that you're having.

Answer (score 2):

Below sed script should work:

```
echo "MSE: 16.80 (MSE is lower) [15 16.3 18.8 11]" | sed 's/.*: \(.*\)\[.*/\1/'
```

It copies the region between : and [ and prints the same.

Answer (score 1):

If your grep supports `P` (*--Perl-regexp*) parameter then you could use the below grep command to parse out the text between `:` and the `[` symbol.

```
grep -oP ':\s*\K.*?(?=\s*\[)'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'MSE: 16.80 (MSE is lower) [15 16.3 18.8 11]. Using sed I want to select only 16.80 (MSE is lower)' | grep -oP ':\s*\K.*?(?=\s*\[)'
16.80 (MSE is lower)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do this would be using a custom field separator in awk:

```
awk -F'[:[] *' '{print $2}'
```

This sets the field separator to either ":" or "[" followed by any number of spaces and prints the second field.

Testing it out with your input:

```
$ awk -F'[:[] *' '{print $2}' <<<"MSE: 16.80 (MSE is lower) [15 16.3 18.8 11]."
16.80 (MSE is lower)
```

Comment: what if `MSE: 16.80 (MSE is lower [or equal]) [15 16.3 18.8 11].`. You assume there are no other `[` in string but you can't (title specify "variable") even it work on the sample.

Comment: Sure, it's not going to work for every conceivable input. Then again, no solution would. Without knowing more about the format of the data, there's no point in making the code any more complex.